# Tab refresh (TabHost)

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I have setup 2 tabs using TabHost, both tabs have a listview. I have setup each listview so that when I click an item an action is completed which is working, the problem I am having is I am having to reload the app for the update to be shown on tab2, what I am wanting is when I open a tab the layout is refreshed for the tab on each open. To get the layout I am including it in my tabs XML.

My adapter has been setup and was working great when in MainActivity, the issue is only occurring since adding TabHost.

```
          // My contentMain
                <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/Onglet1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    layout="@layout/layouttab1" />

            </LinearLayout>


          // My adapter
          ArrayAdapter<Store1> adapter = new MyTitleAdapter();
          ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
          adapterTitle.notifyDataSetChanged();
          myList.setAdapter(adapter); 


    TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab One");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);

    spec.setIndicator("First Tab");
    host.addTab(spec);

    TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    host.setup();

    spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Two");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Secong Tab");
    //host.setOnTabChangedListener();
    host.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: override addontabselectedlistener()

Answer (score 0):

> when you add item in listview, call one method (make it by own) in your adapter

```
public void refreshWishlistAdapter() {
itemList.clear();
itemList.addAll(dbHelper.getallWishlistItems());
itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I am using Mainactivity (contains all code) with TabHost. The tab is populated from a layout.

Comment: yes,but for handling tab1 and tab2 content(after on click of particular tab) what you used??

Comment: I am handling an onClick event only on the listView. I have not linked to the tab1 and tab2.

Answer (score 0):

use this method in fragment, so when you switch fragment this method executes:

```
private boolean isShown = false;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (getView() != null) {
        isShown = true;
        // fetchdata()  show data when page is selected
        fetchData();
    } else {
        isShown = false;
    }
}
```